# Sqlalchemy ORM filter None and False

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i try to filter my entity by column named `valid` and for this i apply simple filter below

```
session.query(Mymodel).filter(Mymodel.valid !=True)
```

The problem is that i have None, False, and True statement for valid field.

How can i do correct filter to return False and None also?

Comment: What about `.filter(Mymodel.valid.isnot(True))`?

Comment: @finswimmer It give all True, Fals and None. It doesn't work

Comment: Please add a minimal example which contains your model. Which database backend are you using?

Comment: @finswimmer please look at  my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.

SQLAlchemy has their own magic method to compose SQL statement and it can operate with `== or !=`

And to get None with False need to do

`session.query(or_(Mymodel.valid == False, Mymodel.valid == None)`